# VB.net adding multiple controls on button click

Tags: vb.net, controls

I'm trying to make a userinterface that generates itself on request (button click)

```
Private Sub Body_new_part_add_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Body_new_part_add.Click
```

So when i add a Combobox as first it's no problem it generates the box & places it on the right position etc.

```
    Dim oTypeBox As New ComboBox
    oTypeBox.Name = "Body_type_" & oBodyPartsNumber
    oTypeBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(7, 78)
    Body_parts.Controls.Add(oTypeBox)
```

Now i want to add another control, a textbox next to the Combobox.

```
    Dim oTypeBox As New ComboBox
    oTypeBox.Name = "Body_type_" & oBodyPartsNumber
    oTypeBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(7, 78)
    Body_parts.Controls.Add(oTypeBox)

    Dim oTextbox As New TextBox
    oTextbox.name = "test"
    oTextbox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(50, 78)
    Body_parts.Controls.Add(oTextbox)
```

This gives me this error.

```
'New' cannot be used on an interface.
```

What do i need to change in order to get this done? I need to add +- 10 controls on each button click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this one**

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim cLeft As Integer = 1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        AddNewTextBox()
    End Sub
    Public Function AddNewTextBox() As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
        Dim txt As New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.Controls.Add(txt)
        txt.Top = cLeft * 25
        txt.Left = 100
        txt.Text = "TextBox " & Me.cLeft.ToString
        cLeft = cLeft + 1
        Return txt
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: but what is point of `function`(?) when You can put that code under button.

Comment: Functions are all about avoiding duplicating your code.

Comment: I know that and I agree... but in this particulary case (question) is unnecessarily.

Comment: Yes, but this is mine coding format that's why i used it.